# Why do elementary topoi have pullbacks?

Tags: ct.category-theory, topos-theory, pullback

In the book of Szabo "Algebra of Proofs", Definition 13.1.9 introduces an elementary topos as a cartesian closed category with a subobject classifier. On the other hand, many other sources including Johnstone add to this definition that the category should contain limits of finite diagrams. For the proof that the requirement on limits of finite diagrams can be removed, Szabo refers the reader to the paper "[Colimits in topoi](https://projecteuclid.org/download/pdf_1/euclid.bams/1183535542)" by Robert Pare who writes in the second paragraph of the section "Preliminaries on topoi" that the existence of finite limits follows from the existence of equalizers which can be derived from appropriate application of the subject classifier. But for finding a monomorphism from the subobject classifier we should have the corresponding pullbacks in the category. Why such pulbacks exist? [The definition of a subobject classifier](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subobject_classifier) works only in one direction: given a monomorphism it yields the characteristic morphism. But for the opposite direction (from a characteristic morphism to a monomorphism) the definition does not say anything on the existence of the corresponding pullbacks.

> **The Question.** Is it true that a cartesian closed category with a subobject classifier indeed has pullbacks?

If yes, could you provide a (desirably simple) proof? Thank you.

Comment: Maybe you should clarify how you define subobject classifier in general ? The definition I would consider standard contains the fact that pullback of monomorphisms exists. (And product and pullback of monomorphisms are enough to get all finite limits because fiber product can be constructed as pullback of a diagonal inclusion)

Comment: @SimonHenry I take the definition of a subobject classifier from Wikipedia: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subobject_classifier

Comment: The definition of "subobject classifier" on the Wikipedia page indeed omits any requirement that pullbacks of "True" along arbitrary morphisms to $\Omega$ should exist. On the other hand, the first sentence on that page implicitly includes that requirement.

Comment: Maybe it's worth mentioning that, if all pullbacks of "true"$:1\to\omega$ exist, then so do all pullbacks of monomorphisms. To pull back a monomorphism $X\to Y$ along a map $f:\to Y$, just compose $f$ with the classifying map of $X\to Y$ and pull "true" back along that composite.

Comment: @AndreasBlass So, this requirement must be included in order to have that more simple definition of an elementary topos. Right? By the way, Wikipedia is open source and I encourage specialists to make necessary corrections there.

Comment: I don't see a way to deduce that requirement, but there's a difference between "I don't see" and "there does not exist". So I'm inclined to wait for more comments or an answer.

Comment: Perhaps one should be aware that Szabo's Algebra of Proofs has a somewhat notorious reputation of having a lot of mistakes in it. (Let me add, for the sake of balance, that I found the book very useful in getting my bearings when I was doing dissertation work; however, I wouldn't take him as an authority on topos theory.)

Comment: @ToddTrimble But I have seen this simplified definition of an elementary topos not only in Szabo.  For example, it is mentioned on page 84 of Goldblatt's book (https://projecteuclid.org/euclid.bia/1403013939), which I hope has a good reputation. And Goldblatt also gives that standard (incomplete) Wikipedia'a definition of a subobject classifier.

Comment: Re Goldblatt: well, unfortunately not entirely. Maybe I'll spend some time thinking about your question.

Comment: @ToddTrimble By the way, another question concerning this simplified definition of an elementary topos. Why it does contain an initial object? If we do not assume any coproducts in the definition, how to generate an initial object from terminal, products, and subobject classifier (even with the correct definition)?

Comment: There's a theorem that an elementary topos has finite colimits. The usual construction (the theorem is that the power object functor $P: E^{op} \to E$ is monadic) is somewhat complicated though; details are in the book by Mac Lane-Moerdijk. A more elementary approach is to develop enough "internal logic" (conjunction, implication, and universal quantification), and then define the initial object as the internal intersection of all subobjects of 1. More on this in this paper: https://www2.mathematik.tu-darmstadt.de/~streicher/CTCL.pdf

Comment: The construction of colimits in a topos was first done by Christian Mikkelsen in his thesis at Aarhus (which is brilliant but difficult to obtain).  The monadicity result was then found by Bob Paré.

Comment: Start with the observation that a subobject of the minimal subobject $0$ of $1$ is $0$ again. Let $X$ be any object. Then there is a "singleton map" $\sigma: X \to PX$ which is monic, and there is also a map $1 \to PX$ which classifies the subobject $id_X: X \to X$. Take the pullback of the subobject $\sigma$ along $0 \to 1 \to PX$. This gives a subobject of $0$, which is $0$ again, and this gives a map $0 \to X$.

Comment: (The last comment was in reply to a comment which has now been deleted.)

Comment: @ToddTrimble Thank you for the explanations with the initial object. I have deleted my comments because I understood how to do that but not so elegantly as you wrote.

Comment: It should also be noted that the reason why this confusion has arisen is because of ambiguity in the usage of **cartesian [closed]**.  For Freyd and Lawvere, cartesian meant having all finite limits, whereas in computer science it has come to mean just products.

Comment: @PaulTaylor: For the record, Mikkelsen’s thesis is no longer difficult to obtain, at least if this is the right one: Christian Juul Mikkelsen, *Lattice Theoretic and Logical Aspects of Elementary Topoi*, 1976 licentiate thesis at Aarhus University, [reprinted in *Theory and Applications of Categories* in 2022](http://www.tac.mta.ca/tac/reprints/articles/29/tr29abs.html), also available from [Mikkelsen’s personal webpage](http://www.chrisjuul.dk/sider/et.htm).

Comment: @PeterLeFanuLumsdaine. I exchanged emails with Christian Mikkelsen sometime after the above comment and found out about his website, but I didn't know about TAC - that's a useful stable citatation, thanks.  (His website is mainly about his own impressive genealogical research, with about 250 of his and his wife's ancestors!  It also shows when Denmark switched from patronymics to surnames.)

Answer (score 20, accepted):

I'll give a counter-example to the claim that having a subobject classifier and being cartesian closed implies the existence of all finite limits. **However**, this is based on the definition of sub-object classifier given on wikipedia (linked in the comment above) that I would consider as incorrect:

The wikipedia definition (at the time this is written) only asks that for every monomorphism $U \hookrightarrow X$ there is a unique map $X \to \Omega$ such that $U$ is the pullback of the universal subobject $1 \hookrightarrow \Omega$, **but** it does not ask that every map $X \to \Omega$ be the classifier of some subobject (i.e. that all pullbacks of the universal subobject exist).

If you add the requirement that every map to $\Omega$ classify something, i.e. that pullback of the map $1 \to \Omega$ exists, then it follows that pullbacks of all monomorphisms exist. Moreover pullbacks of monomorphisms, and the existence of finite products imply (in a  $1$-category) the existence of all finite limits: A fiber product $B \times_A C$ can be recovered as the pullback of the monomorphism $A \to A \times A$ along $B \times C \to A \times A$.

**Consider the category $C$ of finite sets that are not (isomorphic to) the three element sets, with all functions between them.** (feel free to replace three by any odd prime).

- $C$ has products: if $|A \times B| = 3$ then $|A|=3$ or $|B|=3$, so $C$ is stable under product in the category of sets. As it is a full subcategory it follows that these are products in $C$ as well.
- $C$ has a subobject classifier in the sense of Wikipedia's definition, given by the usual $1=\{\top\} \to \Omega = \{ \bot, \top \}$. Indeed given any mono $A \subset B$ in $C$, its classifying map $B \to \Omega$ in set is also a classyfing map in $C$.
- $C$ do not have a subobject classifier in the sense of what I would consider the correct definition: the map $4 \to \Omega$ classying $3 \subset 4$ does not have a pullback, indeed if the pullback $P$ existed there should be exactly three maps $1 \to P$, which is the case for no objects of $C$.
- In particular, this is an example of a pullback in $C$ that does not exists.
- $C$ is cartesian closed. If $X,Y \in C$ then their exponential $X^Y$ in Set is also in $C$ as $|X^Y|=|X|^{|Y|}=3$ has a unique solution given by $|X|=3$ and $|Y|=1$ hence never happen for $X \in C$. Again as $C$ is a full subcategory stable under product this implies that these are exponential objects in $C$.

Comment: Thank you so much for the answer, which has clarified the things.